# XML: Create simple XML string

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

How do I create an XML string in Python 2.7, to look like this :

```
<LIMA DIR="my_dir_here" CMD="my_command_here" OPTION_1="1000" OPTION_2="0"/>
```

Are functions for this? Or do I have to create a string and append to it everything?

Comment: Do you want to create a new XML document that only contains a `LIMA` element? Or do you want to add this element to an already existing XML document? Or something else?

Comment: I only need to create such string. I will pass it further to execute a it. (I'm really new to XML, so I might not know some terms )

Comment: "*I will pass it further to execute a it*". I don't understand this.

Comment: I'm working with some sockets. What I do is that a send a command (like the one described in my post) and wait for a reply. Then I check that reply if it is ok or not.
For this, I am using socket, more exactly `socket.sendall(bytearray(cmd))`.
Those commands are send to a target machine ( a sensor) to check if it is okay. We have tons of commands, like `get_license`, `get_attribute_no1` etc. What I did till now is that I created a function that depending on the some parameteres ( `DIR`, `CMD`, `OPTION_1` etc) it will return a specific string that I will send further to execute it.

Comment: The question is still unclear. What exactly do you mean by "XML string"? To create an element with ElementTree, use the `Element` class: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.